# Youtube SimpleXMLElement prob!em

Tags: php, youtube, simplexml

i'm doing something with php for youtube but xml file that appear in the user picture section, does not appear in the output.

code:

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/davidguetta';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
```

output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/davidguetta
    [published] => 2006-07-26T12:05:23.000-07:00
    [updated] => 2011-08-26T04:34:26.000-07:00
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                            [term] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#userProfile
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/channeltypes.cat
                            [term] => Musician
                        )

                )

        )

    [title] => davidguetta Channel
    [link] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.vlog
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/18F8D522B6C5D32C
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => related
                            [type] => text/html
                            [href] => http://www.davidguetta.com
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => alternate
                            [type] => text/html
                            [href] => http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=davidguetta
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => self
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/davidguetta
                        )

                )

        )

    [author] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => davidguetta
            [uri] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/davidguetta
        )

)
```

why does not the output of the following?

```
<media:thumbnail url='http://i2.ytimg.com/i/uYZ-sFza5K_3GF0LyQAxjg/1.jpg'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SimpleXMLElement is getting confused by ':' in tag names.  You should probably be using the [YouTube PHP Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html) instead.

Comment: i know that. there are too many files, and i wanted to do something so plain and simple. well, how to solve this problem?

Comment: In that case you might find it easier to work with JSON data: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/davidguetta?alt=json

Comment: thanks mjhm (: previously tried but probably i wrote the wrong link json. was now, thank you again...